# merging train and test datasets into one using tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am working with the classic titanic dataset and trying to apply NNs. My data comes already split into train and dev sets. However, I want to merge the datasets together for many things (for example, my own splitting, etc..)

Is there a way I can merge both datasets?
I have looked around and only found information about how to split a dataset, but I was unable to find how to merge them back together.
Any help?

A MWE is provided below!

```
from __future__ import absolute_import,division,print_function,unicode_literals
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc 
import tensorflow as tf 
import seaborn as sns

# URL address of data
TRAIN_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv"
TEST_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv"

# Downloading data
train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
test_file_path  = tf.keras.utils.get_file("eval.csv", TEST_DATA_URL)
# Reading data
data_train = pd.read_csv(train_file_path)
data_test  = pd.read_csv(test_file_path)

MY_DATA= MERGE HERE????? # merge(data_train,data_test)??
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume data_train and data_test have the same number of columns and the column names are the same. Then just do

```
merged_df= pd.concat([data_train, data_test], axis=0)
```